# NAT on Cisco Router between 2 external IP addresses

Tags: networking, nat, cisco

I would like to know if is possible to redirect the traffic on my network when the users try to access an external IP (let's say 20.20.20.20) to redirect them to other external IP (let's say 30.30.30.30).

R1 = Router 1

R2 = Router 2

S1 = Server1

S2 = Server2

```
Users
|
Router
|    |
R1   R2
|    |
S1   S2
```

S1=20.20.20.20

S2=30.30.30.30

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could use NAT to achieve this and have all traffic destined for 20.20.20.20 be NATed to 30.30.30.30.

Hard to understand why you would want to, seems easier to just change the DNS but I guess its valid if you don't control the DNS